# kendo replace (or remove) widget

Tags: kendo-ui

I have my website setup to use the KendoUI framework and I have pulled in some external internet code with forms. To make it look like Kendo i have set the following to make all my select's into a kendoDropDownList:

```
$("select").kendoDropDownList();
```

This works fine. However there is one particular select that I like to convert into a kendoComboBox.
Is there a way to replace or remove the kendoDropDownList from my element and put the kendoComboBox instead.

Thanks in advance

Karel

Answer (score 0):

If you need to single out one `select`, then you'll need to use a more specific jQuery selector (an id, text, CSS class, containing div, etc.).

For example, if your `select` elements have id's, you could do something like:

```
$("select:not([id='myComboBox'])").kendoDropDownList();
$("select[id='myComboBox']").kendoComboBox();
```

Really, you just need to do *something* to separate that `select` from the rest of them.

If you are unfamiliar with jQuery selectors (or just need a refresher), you can find the full documentation here: http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Here's an example fiddle of this working: http://jsfiddle.net/ATNkC/1/